# Strange Characters showing in Classic ASP Coded blog

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

For months I have had an issue with characters appearing after someone has posted a blog.  The blog is coded with Classic ASP.  Example characters appearing are: â€Ž or â€™...  it appears to happen for foreign characters the most.

Any help would to avoid this issue would be greatly appreciated..

neojakey

Answer (score 1):

The page is sending UTF-8 but it fails to set `CharSet="UTF-8"` so the receiving browser just thinks its the default local character set probably Windows-1252.

Alternativly the original article is posted as UTF-8 but the receiving mechanisim doesn't know that and treats the incoming characters as the servers local character set.

To correct ensure all pages use CodePage=65001, are saved as UTF-8 and set CharSet="UTF-8", any other problems will likely be the result of bad data already corrupted in earlier submissions.  You will need to code up some recovery for the bad data.